# "Зачем" тут может писаться и так и сяк (слитно и раздельно)?

Tags: орфография, наречия

Это о начале работы в архиве.

> И всё же я только начала, только тронула то, зачем пришла.

Comment: Я бы раздельно написал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***И всё же я только начала, только тронула то, за чем пришла.***

Это местоименная связь "то — за чем", раздельное написание предлога.

Слитное написание может быть при изъяснительной связи: Она так и не смогла объяснить того, зачем (для чего, с какой целью) приходила.